# Como muestro los diccionarios dentro de un diccionario pero con saltos de linea?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Ahora mi problema es el siguiente:

Tengo este diccionario pero, ¿Qué hago para que el diccionario de clases de cada estudiante se me imprima en una línea diferente?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
Estudiante={
  'Estudiante1': {'Name1':'carlos','Name2':'santana','Lastname1':'santana','Lastename2':'Mendieta','Edad':16,
  'clases1':{'clase 1':'Matematicas','clase 2':'Contabilidad','clase 3':'Redaccion',}
  },
  'Estudiante2': {'Name1':'James','Name2':'jhona','Lastname1':'halpert','Garick':'apellido','Edad':20,
  'clases2':{'clase 1':'Matematicas','clase 2':'Contabilidad','clase 3':'Redaccion',}
  },
  'Estudiante3': {'Name1':'Michel','Name2':'teodore','Lastname1':'lang','Lastname2':'scott','Edad':19,
  'clases3':{'clase 1':'Matematicas','clase 2':'Contabilidad','clase 3':'Redaccion',}
  }
}
for x in range(3):
    print(Estudiante[f'Estudiante{x+1}'])
# Cuando lo imprimo sale así
{'Name1': 'Axel', 'Name2': 'Ruben', 'Lastname1': 'Mora', 'Lastename2': 'Mendieta', 'Edad': 16, 'clases1': {'clase 1': 'Matematicas', 'clase 2': 'Contabilidad', 'clase 3': 'Redaccion'}}
{'Name1': 'James', 'Name2': 'jhona', 'Lastname1': 'halpert', 'Garick': 'apellido', 'Edad': 20, 'clases2': {'clase 1': 'Matematicas', 'clase 2': 'Contabilidad', 'clase 3': 'Redaccion'}}
{'Name1': 'Michel', 'Name2': 'teodore', 'Lastname1': 'lang', 'Lastname2': 'scott', 'Edad': 19, 'clases3': {'clase 1': 'Matematicas', 'clase 2': 'Contabilidad', 'clase 3': 'Redaccion'}}
```

Algo así me gustaría:

```
{'Name1': 'Axel', 'Name2': 'Ruben', 'Lastname1': 'Mora', 'Lastename2': 'Mendieta', 'Edad': 16,
 'clases1': {'clase 1': 'Matematicas', 'clase 2': 'Contabilidad', 'clase 3': 'Redaccion'}}
{'Name1': 'James', 'Name2': 'jhona', 'Lastname1': 'halpert', 'Garick': 'apellido', 'Edad': 20,
 'clases2': {'clase 1': 'Matematicas', 'clase 2': 'Contabilidad', 'clase 3': 'Redaccion'}}
{'Name1': 'Michel', 'Name2': 'teodore', 'Lastname1': 'lang', 'Lastname2': 'scott', 'Edad': 19,
 'clases3': {'clase 1': 'Matematicas', 'clase 2': 'Contabilidad', 'clase 3': 'Redaccion'}}
```

Comment: Tienes que reemplazar el `print(alumno)` por varios `print()` (nombres, edad, etc) y luego en un ciclo `for` recorres la lista de clases, imprimiendo cada una en una línea.

Comment: puedes utilizar `pprint`

Answer (score 0):

Recorres el diccionario y puedes utilizar `isinstance(v, dict)`  para generar el salto de linea.

```
for est in Estudiantes.values():
    print('{', end='')
    for k, v in est.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            print( f"\n{k}: {v}")
        else:
            print(f"{k}: {v}", end=", ")
```

Otra forma:

```
for est in Estudiantes.values():
    print('{', end='')
    for k, v in est.items():
        fr = ( f"\n{k}: {v}\n" if isinstance(v, dict) else f"{k}: {v}, ")
        print( fr, end='')
```